# Pyspark Sql writing DF to text and preserve headers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark sql dataframe, I want to write out to text, unit separated. I understand the process is to first `concat_ws` then `coalesce(1)` to a single cell df so it can be written like so.

```
outputDF = df.select(concat_ws('\x1f',*df.columns))
outputDF = outputDF.coalesce(1)

print('PRINTING PREVIEW')
outputDF.show(truncate=0)

outputDF.write.format("text").option("header","true").mode("overwrite").save(s3bucket_somewhere)
```

I have a show() step which, gives me the output that I expect, something like :

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------  
----------------------------------------------------------------  
----------------------------------------------------------------  
+
|concat_ws( , name, age,color)|
+----------------------------------------------------------------  
----------------------------------------------------------------  
----------------------------------------------------------------  
+
|adam 30 red | 
|bob 22 blue | 

+----------------------------------------------------------------  
----------------------------------------------------------------  
----------------------------------------------------------------  
+

only showing top 20 rows
```

But when viewing the file written to S3 it doesn't include the header.Even although I set it in the write options it seems to not be included. I have tried using alias during the concat_ws step but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text file format does not support the use of headers. You can write a CSV file instead, which will give essentially the same file as the text file, only that the file extension is csv rather than txt.

e.g.

```
outputDF = df.select(concat_ws('\x1f',*df.columns))

outputDF.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("overwrite").save(s3bucket_somewhere)
```

Or you can skip the `concat_ws` step and write to a csv directly.

e.g.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").option("sep", "\x1f").mode("overwrite").save(s3bucket_somewhere)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately when I do this step the file is changed, when opening .csv in an editor I can see each second line has the entire row in quotes.

Comment: how about `outputDF.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").option("sep", "\x00").mode("overwrite").save(s3bucket_somewhere)`?

Comment: Hey Mck, thanks! Unfortunately keeping \x1f is a requirement I can't change. I tried creating a seperate df for the column row only and appending them using union but because we don't have pyspark ver 3, we can't use missingcolumns so that one is off the table too.

Comment: the `\x00` is not related to your `\x1f` requirement. It's just for creating a dummy separator for the CSV file format, so that there won't be quotes around the entries. Try using it with after `concat_ws('\x1f`')` as in the first code snippet?

Comment: Excellent, that worked! Not sure how the dummy sep solved the issue but great stuff thank you. Marking this as correct; ideally I would have liked to manage it using the text function, as the requirement is for txt in s3 but this is a step in the right direction. Thanks again.